# How to reduce this Query (SQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, reduce

```
$sql = "SELECT min(id) FROM matchTrip where userTripId = :tripId AND 
matchStrength = (SELECT MIN(matchStrength) FROM matchTrip where userTripId = :tripId) ";
```

Is it possible to reduce this query So that performance is increased and time to execute this query is reduced?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `and speed is reduced` or and speed is increased..?

Comment: nope...not yet....you still need some century to break sachin record....

Comment: I dont want to go with language anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for minimum value of `id` for minimum value of `matchStrength`. Therefore, you can do:

```
SELECT 
  id 
FROM 
  matchTrip 
WHERE 
  userTripId = :tripId 
ORDER BY 
  matchStrength, 
  id 
LIMIT 1
```

in any case you need to have index via `matchStrength` (I think you already have it for `id` field). As for performance - you have to do measures, there's no certain other way to be sure that one thing is better than another in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM matchTrip where userTripId = :tripId ORDER BY matchStrength, id LIMIT 1";
```